# what is application signature in hyperledger fabric and how to set it?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

[image]

what is Application's own signature in this context, and how can someone using hyperledger fabric node SDK can set the application's signature?

Answer (score 0):

the application that you are talking about is simply a client app which talks to the ledger. The issue here is not the client app, the issue here is that you need a proper endorsement policy which establishes how anything goes onto the ledger.

Imagine this scenario ...

you have 2 orgs, *Org1* and *Org2*, both owning one peer, *P1* belongs to *Org1*, *P2* belongs to *Org2* and both peers joined on a channel, let's call it *defaultchannel*.

you deploy and instantiate your chaincode and set a basic endorsement policy which is 1-Of.

Each org has a client application, running against their own peer. When Org1 submits a transaction to the ledger, its validity is endorsed by itself, but not by the second org, because your policy requires only one to accomplish this. Basically in any network where you have more than one org, you really want a proper endorsement policy. 2-Of would work in the case of our example as any transaction would need to be validated by both orgs and that gives the ledger much better integrity.

Bottom line, your fabric network needs to be properly built and protected, especially in a production environment and this allows it to be protected by any client apps which have rights to interact with it. Your network being protected means that it doesn't matter how a client app is built and what it tries to do, it won't be able to bypass mechanisms such as the endorsement mechanisms.